# Find if request is child action request before controller context is available

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

In a simple mvc 4 app I installed Ninject.MVC3 nuget package.

This is my controller, very basic, ISomeClass is being injected in the constructor by ninject.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISomeClass _someClass;

    public HomeController(ISomeClass someclass)
    {
        _someClass = someclass;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult MiniView()
    {
        return PartialView("miniview", _someClass.GetName());
    }
}
```

This is SomeClass

```
public class SomeClass : ISomeClass
{
    private readonly string _someName;

    public SomeClass(string someName)
    {
        _someName = someName;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return _someName;
    }
}
```

In Index.cshtml view I have

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("MiniView","Home"); }
```

Now in NinjectWebCommon when I go to register the service I need to know if the request was a child action request or not. Like when I call `Html.RenderAction`. This is what I am trying but it is not working.

```
kernel.Bind<ISomeClass>().To<SomeClass>()
      .WithConstructorArgument("someName", c => IsChildAction(c) ? "Child" : "Nope");
```

IsChildAction method - Always returns false.

```
private static bool IsChildAction(Ninject.Activation.IContext c)
{
   var handler = HttpContext.Current.Handler;

   /*Cant do this, ChildActionMvcHandler is internal*/        
   return handler is System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ChildActionMvcHandler;

//OR

   //This is how ControllerContext.IsChildAction gets its value in System.Web.Mvc but      
   //RouteData.DataTokens is empty for me       
   return ((MvcHandler)handler).RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens
                              .ContainsKey("ParentActionViewContext");
}
```

Any ideas if this can be done?

ps: this is not actual code, just trying something. Is this something I should definately not do? Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up checking if the current request has a previous handler. Seems like it is being set only on child actions.

```
HttpContext.Current.PreviousHandler != null && 
HttpContext.Current.PreviousHandler is MvcHandler;
```

Comment: (HttpContext.Current.PreviousHandler as MvcHandler) != null

Answer (score 1):

If the `IsChildAction` is something only known at runtime and within the controller, I suggest you don't pass an instance of `SomeClass`. Pass a **factory** instead and build that instance when you need it using the factory. I think that approach would work best in your case.

For using the **factory** you can use **Ninject.Extensions.Factory** or implement one yourself:

```
public class SomeClassFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public SomeClassFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public SomeClass Create(string name, bool isChild)
    {
        var childString = (isChild) ? "Child" : "Nope";
        return _kernel.Get<SomeClass>(new ConstructorArgument("someName", childString));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
After you said a **Factory** wouldn't work, the only way I could figure out for you to have access to the `RequestContext` during controller creation would be with a custom controller factory. You won't be able to get it statically in your bindings, I'm afraid.

The code below performs resolution on your `SomeClass` at runtime depending on whether the `RequestContext` contains the information about child action. It uses a custom `IControllerFactory` which certainly could have a better implementation, but it is enough to show how it can be done.

```
internal class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    internal const string ParentActionViewContextToken = "ParentActionViewContext";
    private readonly IResolutionRoot _resolutionRoot;

    public CustomControllerFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        _resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        //You can improve this later if you want -> you'll need to figure out if your controller will fit into this case
        //You can use marker interfaces, common supertype, etc... that's up to you
        if (controllerName.Equals("home", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            var controllerType = typeof (HomeController);
            var isChild = requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.ContainsKey(ParentActionViewContextToken);

            var constructorArgument = new ConstructorArgument("someName", (isChild) ? "Child" : "Nope");
            var requestForDependency = _resolutionRoot.CreateRequest(typeof(IServiceClient), null, new Parameter[] { constructorArgument }, true, true);
            var dependency = _resolutionRoot.Resolve(requestForDependency).SingleOrDefault();

            return (IController)_resolutionRoot.Get(controllerType, new ConstructorArgument("service", dependency));
        }

        //Will go through the default pipeline (IDependencyResolver will be called, not affecting DI of other controllers)
        return base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
    }
}
```

Make sure you bind it:

`kernel.Bind<IControllerFactory>().To<CustomControllerFactory>();`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did think about the factory approach. But I need to figure out if this is a child request during or prior to the controller creation(for eg like in a custom controller factory), so passing a factory didnt work. I tried to simplify the question here, apologize if it caused confusion.

Comment: Are you going to need this for specific controllers or for all of them? I have a solution in mind but I'd like to know that

Comment: Will need this for all of them.

Comment: Then it is even easier, you don't need the above check. Please see if the answer fits :)